# IF Function Result not shown

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a formula in a IF function but it does not appear as the result

=IF(J5-TIMEVALUE("00:30")

Example : 
I got a start time at 10.10am and end time at 10.50am
the time diff is at 40min, the IF function did not appear as result of 10min.
It had given me a Zero Value instead.

But my other lines with time diff more than an hour, the result is shown
Help please

Comment: None of the discussion relates to your formula.  What does the 10 minutes relate to?  What formula and what values gave you a result of zero?  It sounds like all of the results are shown.  What kind of formatting are you using to display the results?  Are you using a format that doesn't display minutes?

Comment: Check the format of the cells (Make sure it is a time cell and not a date cell)... cos the result might show difference in days rather than minutes

Answer (score 0):

No `IF` formula needed:

**A1** = "10:10"

**B1** = "10:50"

Formula:

```
=B1-A1-TIMEVALUE("00:30")
```

Result

```
00:10
```